# Is it possible to align the button in Meteor {{> quickForm}}?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I am using `{{> quickForm}}` and it is working fine. It is just the location of the button that is positioned in the left side by default.

Can I change the position to the middle instead?

Answer (score 0):

Sure You can change the position by applying class like below:
`

{{#autoForm collection="Books" id="insertBookForm" type="insert"}}

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
```

{{/autoForm}}`